# Removing duplicate lines from files keeping the original order in csv

Tags: powershell

I have searched but haven't found reasonable solution.
In csv file, there is many columns but in first column I need to keep unique match and remove duplicates, but keeping the original order at the same time...

Data example:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | Data1 |
| A | Data2 |
| A | Data3 |
| B | Data4 |
| B | Data5 |
| C | Data6 |
| C | Data7 |
| E | Data8 |
| E | Data 9 |
| E | Data10 |
| E | Data11 |

Desired:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | Data1 |
|  | Data2 |
|  | Data3 |
| B | Data4 |
|  | Data5 |
| C | Data6 |
|  | Data7 |
| E | Data8 |
|  | Data 9 |
|  | Data10 |
|  | Data11 |

So far i can see from console nice list, but haven't found a way how to display only first unique value.

`Import-Csv 'C:\Data\smt.csv' -Delimiter ';'  |  Group-Object -Property Column1 | Where-Object { $_.count -ge 1 }`   -> I can see how much duplicates i have..

If i add `| Foreach-Object { $_.Group }`  then it shows nice list but if i try to remove it, it will mess up the original order.

Maybe someone can give me a tip how to handle it or should I use some other tool, rather than Powershell.

Sincerly

Comment: For future reference, when asking a related question, it is preferable to display the data as is (in this case a plain text csv) instead of html table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this:

```
$csv = @'
Column1  Column2
A  Data1
A  Data2
A  Data3
B  Data4
B  Data5
C  Data6
C  Data7
E  Data8
E  Data9
E  Data10
E  Data11
'@ -replace ' +',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv | Group-Object Column1 | ForEach-Object {
    
    $i = $true

    $_.Group.foreach({
        
        if(-not $i){
            $_.Column1 = ''
        }

        $i = $false
    })
}
```

In your case, the code would be:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Data\smt.csv' -Delimiter ';'
$csv | Group-Object Column1 | ForEach-Object {
    
    $i = $true

    $_.Group.foreach({
        
        if(-not $i){
            $_.Column1 = ''
        }

        $i = $false
    })
}
```

Result:

```
PS /> $csv

Column1 Column2
------- -------
A       Data1  
        Data2  
        Data3  
B       Data4  
        Data5  
C       Data6  
        Data7  
E       Data8  
        Data9
        Data10 
        Data11
```

Comment: @Linyx happy to help. If the answer was helpful please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).